# Excel sheet making decision based on group of values

Tags: c#, xml, vba, excel

I need to make a decision based upon a bunch of values:
My first excel sheet looks like this:
Example:

```
Number  Thing1  Thing2 Thing3 .... Thing7
1        0         1     0           1
2        1         1     0           0
```

I have another excel sheet that has the meanings associated with these values:
Example:

```
  Meaning  Thing1  Thing2 Thing3 .... Thing7
  Powerful   0        1     0           1
  Medium     1        0     1           0
  Low        1        1     0           0
```

Now I need to make a decision as to which number has what designation.
The first sheet after processing should like this:

```
Number  Thing1  Thing2 Thing3 .... Thing7    PowerLevel
1        0         1     0           1        Powerful
2        1         1     0           0        Low
```

Is this possible in excel ? If it is not then I am open to solutions from C# programming or any other language. Or maybe even an idea of how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

We need to create a **key** that we can use for *Match() and INDEX()* functions.
In *Sheet2* cell **I2** we enter:

```
=B2 & C2 & D2 & E2 & F2 & G2 & H2
```

and copy down:

[image]

Then in *Sheet1,* cell **I2** we enter:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A$2:A$6,MATCH(B2 & C2 & D2 & E2 & F2 & G2 & H2,Sheet2!I$2:I$6,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

We are basically converting a **binary** code into a *string* that Excel can easily handle.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But does the value need to be unique in Sheet 2 "I" Column ? What if multiple rows come up with same combination? I would want to have both conditions (Meaning) to be displayed.

Comment: @Rohit  Then this simple approach would not work...........it only retrieves the first instance.